# How to atomically check if a key exists in a map and add it if it doesn't exist

Tags: concurrency, clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to generate a new key that doesn't exist in my map (atom), then immediately add it to my map and return the key. However, the check for the key and the update are not done atomically. I am wondering how to do this atomically so that it is safe for concurrency.

Ideally this key is short enough to type but hard to guess (so a user can create a session, and his/her friends can join with the key). So 0,1,2,3... is not ideal since a user can try enter sessions n-1. Something like UUID where I don't have to worry about collisions is also not ideal. I was planning on generating a short random string (e.g. "udibwi") but I've used `rand-int 25` in the code snippet below to simplify the problem.

I've written a function which randomly generates a key.   It checks if the map contains it. If it already does then try a new key. If it doesn't, associate it to my map and then return the key.

This works but I don't think it is safe for multiple threads. Is there a way to do this using atoms or is there a better way?

```
(defonce sessions (atom {}))

(defn getNewSessionId []
  (let [id (rand-int 25)]
    (if (contains? @sessions id) 
      (createNewId) 
      (do 
        (swap! sessions assoc id "")
        id))))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Race conditions and clojure Atoms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660647/race-conditions-and-clojure-atoms)

Comment: Anything that happens in a function passed to `swap!` is by definition atomic and thread safe. Just pass a smarter function than `assoc` to `swap!`.

Comment: @JaredSmith I was thinking about passing a function that contains the id generation logic to `swap!`. However, `swap!` returns the value that was swapped in, so is there a clean way to get the new id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do too much at once. Having that one function generate an ID and update the atom is complicating things. I'd break this down into three functions:

- A function that generates an ID based on an existing map
- A function that updates a *plain, immutable map* using the above function
- A function that updates an atom (although this will be so simple after implementing the previous two functions that it may not be necessary at all).

Something like:

```
; Notice how this doesn't deal with atoms at all
(defn generate-new-id [old-map]
  (let [new-id (rand-int 25)]
    (if (old-map new-id) ; or use "contains?"
      (recur old-map) ; Using "recur" so we don't get a StackOverflow
      new-id)))

; Also doesn't know anything about the atom
(defn assoc-new-id [old-map]
  (let [new-id (generate-new-id old-map)]
    (assoc old-map new-id "")))

(defonce data (atom {}))

(defn swap-new-id! []
  (swap! data assoc-new-id))
```

The main changes:

- Everything that could be removed from the atom swapping logic was moved to its own function. This allows you to just pass the function handling all the logic to `swap!` and it will be handled atomically.
- Clojure uses dash-case, not camelCase.
- I used `recur` instead of actual recursion so you won't get a `StackOverflow` while the ID is being brute-forced.

Of course though, this suffers from problems if the available number of IDs left is small. It may take a long time for it to "find" an available ID via brute-force. You might be better off using a "generator" backed by an `atom` to produce IDs atomically starting from 0:

```
(defn new-id-producer []
  (atom -1))

(defn generate-id [producer]
  (swap! producer inc)) ; "swap!" returns the new value that was swapped in

(let [producer (new-id-producer)]
 ; Could be run on multiple threads at once
 (doseq [id (repeatedly 5 #(generate-id producer))]
   (println id))) 
0
1
2
3
4
=> nil
```

I tried to write an example of this operating on multiple threads at once:

```
(let [producer (new-id-producer)

      ; Emulate the "consumption" of IDs
      consume (fn []
                (doseq [id (repeatedly 20 #(generate-id producer))]
                  (println (.getId (Thread/currentThread)) id)))]

  (doto (Thread. consume)
        (.start))

  (doto (Thread. consume)
        (.start)))

37 0
3738 1
38 3
38 4
38 5
38 6
38 7
38 8
38 9
38 10
38 11
38 12
38 13
38 14
38 15
38 16
38 17
38 18
38 19
38 20
38 21
 2
37 22
37 23
37 24
37 25
37 26
37 27
37 28
37 29
37 30
37 31
37 32
37 33
37 34
37 35
37 36
37 37
37 38
37 39
```

But the un-synchronized nature of the printing to the outstream made this output a mess. If you squint a bit though, you can see that the threads (with Thread IDs of 37 and 38) are taking turns.

---

If you need the new ID returned, the only clean way I know of that doesn't involve `locking` is to use a *second* atom to get the returned ID out of the swapping function. This requires getting rid of `assoc-new-id`:

```
(defn generate-new-id [old-map]
  (let [new-id (rand-int 25)]
    (if (old-map new-id)
      (recur old-map)
      new-id)))

(defn swap-new-id! [old-map]
  (let [result-atom (atom nil)]

    (swap! data (fn [m]
                  (let [id (generate-new-id m)]
                    (reset! result-promise id) ; Put the ID in the result atom
                    (assoc m id ""))))

    @result-promise)) ; Then retrieve it here
```

Or, if a very inefficient solution is fine and you're using Clojure 1.9.0, you can just search the maps to find what key was added using `clojure.set.difference`:

```
(defn find-new-id [old-map new-map]
  (clojure.set/difference (set (keys new-map))
                          (set (keys old-map))))

(defn swap-new-id! []
  (let [[old-map new-map] (swap-vals! data assoc-new-id)] ; New in 1.9.0
    (find-new-id new-map old-map)))
```

But again, this is *very* inefficient. It requires two iterations of each map.

Comment: I'm passing out for the night, so if you have any questions, I unfortunately won't be able to answer them for ~9 hours.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed writeup and tips about Clojure! A key issue I was trying to solve which I didn't convey well is that I want to return the new id. So is there a way to make swap-new-id! return the new id?

Comment: @AnuBandi Updated with a couple potential solutions at the bottom. I agree with Alan though. The fact that this is resulting in ugly code suggests that what you're trying to do is off. When you have more code written, you may want to submit it to Code Review or Reddit's Clojure subreddit for completely alternative approaches.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, the solution with the promise is safe because all accesses to data are within an anonymous function. And `swap!` will ensure this is done atomically or retry so the result-promise will always have the id that was inserted.

Can we use `with-local-vars` instead of promise here? Is it more efficient?

Comment: @AnuBandi I'm actually going to have to update my answer. I realized that `promise` actually can't be used here; you'll need to use an atom. The swapping function has the potential to run multiple times to resolve conflicts, but a promise can only be delivered once. I'll have to do that on my next break or when I get home. Sorry, that was a dumb oversight on my part. The fix will just be to make the `promise` an `atom`, and change `deliver` to `reset!`. I used `promise` because it conceptually makes more sense, but the intentional limitation of only allowing a single delivery is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please update your question with the reason you are trying to do this?  There are almost certainly better solutions than the one you propose.

If you really want to generate unique keys for a map, there are 2 easy answers.

(1) For coordinated keys, you could use an `atom` to hold an integer of the last key generated.

```
(def last-map-key (atom 0))
(defn new-map-key (swap! last-map-key inc))
```

which is guaranteed to generate unique new map keys.

(2) For uncoordinated keys, use a UUID [as with `clj-uuid/v1`](https://github.com/danlentz/clj-uuid)

(3) If you really insist on your original algorithm, you could use a Clojure `ref`, but that is an abuse of it's intended purpose.

Comment: I've simplified the problem by using `(rand-int 25)` as the id, but I need something that is both simple to type and hard to guess, so various users can join a session once someone creates one. For this reason neither monodically increasing numbers nor UUID is ideal. I was planning on generating short strings as ids (e.g. "ruvnwl").

Maybe I'll try to generate the keys to ensure they are unique and sudo random. But I'm surprised there isn't a simple way to do what I was asking in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the information about which id was the last one in the atom as well.

```
(defonce data
  (atom {:sessions {}
         :latest-id nil}))

(defn generate-session-id [sessions]
  (let [id (rand-int 25)]
    (if (contains? sessions id)
      (recur sessions)
      id)))

(defn add-new-session [{:keys [sessions] :as data}]
  (let [id (generate-session-id sessions)]
    (-> data
        (assoc-in [:sessions id] {})
        (assoc :latest-id id))))

(defn create-new-session! []
  (:latest-id (swap! data add-new-session)))
```

As Carcigenicate shows, by using `swap-vals!` it is derivable from the before and after states, but it's simpler to just keep around.